# Soft keyboard shrinks activity

Tags: android, keyboard

I am writing custom soft keyboard. The problem is, that on Motorola Moto G it shrinks activity. This happens on any text input.

For some reason, this does not happen on another android, HTC One. What I am missing?

[Some notepad withoud keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJRqV.jpg), [notepad with my keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJLTm.jpg).

When I click on a button, everything become OK for a moment, that's why I took a shot of a screen phone instead of taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, look for your activity and try adding

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```